# Get Selected Index on next page from Drop Down list

Tags: php, html, request, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a form

Whose Action is test4.php

```
        <h1>Signup for Free Account</h1>            

        <div class="login-fields">

            <p>Create your free account:</p>
```

It takes User First Name

```
            <div class="field">
                <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="First Name" onBlur="validate(this,document.getElementById('FName'));" class="login" />
                <span id="FName" class="help"></span>

            </div> <!-- /field -->
```

It Takes user Last Name

```
            <div class="field">
                <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>    
                <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="" placeholder="Last Name" class="login" onBlur="validate(this,document.getElementById('LName'));" />
               <span id="LName" class="help"> 
            </div> 
            <!-- /field -->
```

It takes Email Id

```
            <div class="field">
                <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" class="login" onBlur="validate(this,document.getElementById('Uemail'));" />
                <span id="Uemail" class="help">
            </div> <!-- /field -->
```

It takes Unique Id for User

```
            <div class="field">
                <label for="uniqueid">Unique Id:</label>
                <input type="text" id="uniqueid" name="uniqueid" value="" placeholder="Unique Id" class="login" onBlur="validate(this,document.getElementById('Uid'));" />
                <span id="Uid" class="help">
            </div> <!-- /field -->
```

It takes Password

```
            <div class="field">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" class="login" onBlur="validate(this,document.getElementById('pwd'));"   />
                <span id="pwd" class="help">
            </div> <!-- /field -->
```

It conforms password

```
            <div class="field">
                <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="login" onBlur="validate(this,document.getElementById('cpwd'));" />
               <span id="cpwd" class="help"> 
            </div> <!-- /field -->
```

It takes currency

```
                            <div class="field">
                <label for="currency">Currency:</label>
                                    <select id="currency" name="currency">
                                        <option value="0">Indian Rupee</option>
                                        <option value="1">US Dollar</option>
                                        <option value="2">Euro</option>
                                        <option value="3">Yen</option>
                                        <option value="4">Pound</option>
                                        <option value="5">Australian Dollar</option>
                                        <option value="6">Canadian Dollar</option>
                                        <option value="7">Swedish Krone</option>
                                        <option value="8">Hong Kong Dollar</option>
                                        <option value="9">New Zealand Dollar</option>                                            
                                    </select>
            </div> <!-- /field -->

        </div> <!-- /login-fields -->

        <div class="login-actions">
            <input type="submit" class="button btn btn-primary btn-large" id="subReg" value="Register"/>                
        </div> <!-- .actions -->

    </form>
```

And in `test4.php`
I am fetching it like

```
$currency= $_REQUEST['currency'];
```

But I am error as

```
Notice: Undefined index: currency in C:\xampp\htdocs\money_manager\test4.php
```

How to retrieve the `selected index value` on `test4.php`

Validate all function is used for js check

```
function validateAll()
{
    var Gfn=document.getElementById("firstname");
    var Gln=document.getElementById("lastname");
    var Gid=document.getElementById("uniqueid");
    var Gemail=document.getElementById("email");
    var Gpwd=document.getElementById("password");
    var Gcpwd=document.getElementById("confirm_password");

    if(Gfn.value.length === 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("FName").innerHTML="This field can not be empty.";
        firstname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(Gln.value.length === 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("LName").innerHTML="This field can not be empty.";
        lastname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(Gemail.value.length === 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("Uemail").innerHTML="This field can not be empty.";
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(Gid.value.length === 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("Uid").innerHTML="This field can not be empty.";
        uniqueid.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(Gpwd.value.length === 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("pwd").innerHTML="This field can not be empty.";
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(Gcpwd.value.length === 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("cpwd").innerHTML="This field can not be empty.";
        confirm_password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(validpwd() === "error")
    {
        document.getElementById("cpwd").innerHTML="Password and confirm password does not match";
        confirm_password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(validemail() === "error")
    {
        document.getElementById("Uemail").innerHTML="please enter valid email.";
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }




    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is test4.php located in the same folder as the file with the form (let's call it `index.php`)? Can we see more of the form's code?

Comment: How to get the selected index on the next page..??

Comment: Is there no way to get the selected insdex

Comment: What do you get on test4.php if you `var_dump($_REQUEST)`?

Comment: Currency is not getting submitted.. only the first 4 are getting submitted and

Comment: Which 4 are getting submitted? Also, is this the complete code for the form?

Comment: name , password, email id and last name are getting submitted but selected is not

Comment: Ok, we definitely need to see the complete form code, as well as the JS function `validate()`

Comment: Validate is given in the Question.. i am updating the form

Comment: You have a bunch of onblur attributes that call another, different function called `validate()`, which is not `validateAll()`. You also call `validpwd()` and `validemail()` and in the `validemail()` call you reference `document.getElementById("Uemail")` but there is no element with that id.

Answer (score 0):

Either you put it in a `<form>` or you make a redirection to another page with all the datas in the URL (GET method).